# Notation of column wise operations in a matrix

Tags: matrices, notation

I'm describing a column wise operation in a paper, but I'm unsure about what is the correct notation.

$c[i] = \text{max}(C[:, i])$

The equation above is supposed to mean that each dimension $i$ of the vector $c$ is equal to  the maximum value among all rows in the column $i$ of matrix $C$.

Is it clear or is there a better way to describe the operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks very much like “programmer notation” to me. That is not necessarily a bad thing if that is your audience.

For a more “mathematical” way of expressing this, you would proceed like this:

First, for some reason it is common not to subscript a matrix directly, but to introduce new names for it’s entries: $C = (c_{ij})_{1 \leq i \leq m, 1 \leq j \leq n}$ (where $m \times n$ is the type of the matrix). If you use the lower case version of the letter you used to name the matrix (like I did), you will probably be understood even if you don’t do this. You can also use $C_{ij}$ for the entries but you should mention it explicitly (unless it is common in your field).

Second, since we now used $c$ for the entries of the matrix, we will have to use another letter for your vector $c$. Pick one, I will use $d$.

Third, using $C[:,i]$ to denote the $i$-th column is very unusual. The normal (though arguably less elegant) way is to express the “loop” explicitly. Also, conventionally, $i$ is used for row indices, $j$ is used for columns (but that is not very important). This results in something like
$$d_j = \max_{1 \leq i \leq m} c_{ij}.$$

Comment: It turns out this can be expressed in a pretty simple way. I was indeed thinking too much as a programmer. Thanks!