# Notation for computing the maximum across each column of a 2-dimensional matrix

Tags: matrices, notation

Is there a concise notation for computing the highest number of each column of a 2-dimensional matrix $A$?

edit: To clarify, the result should be a vector with the length the same as the number of columns in $A$, and each element of this vector should be the maximum number of the corresponding column of $A$.

If it is easier to concisely express this operation for a single column of $A$, that could also work. Then I could write that it's an operation performed on each column.

Comment: Welcome. Remember to use MathJax for writing math in this site.

Comment: @DaniloGregorin Thanks, fixed.

Comment: Be patient, with time and good work it will not take long untill you have enough privileges to use almot all functions of the site. Since you edited the question to explain better your thoghts, i will upvote it. Consider as a motivation.    ;)

Comment: I found out that this question was answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1175253/notation-of-column-wise-operations-in-a-matrix?rq=1).